# How are Hyperplane Heatmaps created and how should they be interpreted?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, kernel-trick

For nonlinear data, when we are using Support Vector Machines, we can use kernels such as Gaussian RBF, Polynomial, etc to achieve linearity in a different (potentially unknown to us) feature space and *the algorithm learns a maximal separating hyperplane in that feature space*.

My question is how do we create heatmaps such as the one seen in the image below to show this max. separating hyperplane in our original space and how should it be interpreted?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decision function $g(x) \in \{-1, 1\}$ of a kernelized SVM is given by

$$g(x) = \mathrm{sgn}(f(x)), \\
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i y_i k(x_i, x) + b,$$

where the training set is $\{(x_i, y_i)_i\}_{i=1}^n$, $k$ is a kernel, and $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^n$, $b$ are learned. If $g(x)=1$, $x$ is classified to the positive class. If $g(x)=-1$, $x$ is classified to the negative class.

The set $\{x \mid f(x)=g(x)=0\}$ consists of all the points lying exactly at the boundary. These are the points on the blue solid line. The heat map shows $f(x)$. That is, the magenta region shows points such that $f(x)>0$ and the cyan region show points $x$ such that $f(x) < 0$.

Comment: Then indeed you did not ask it properly. Are you asking how to write code to generate them? Or are you asking how an actual implementation works? If you mean the second one, then you could have asked it without talking about SVM. You want "How do implementations of surface plots work?", correct?

Comment: As you said, we cannot try all points in the plane. Basically you will evaluate the function on a finite set of points and do some smoothing. I do not know the details. I imagine there are many algorithms to do so. Also, this is probably not the right place to ask.